# Need help identifying species of Bonsai tree

Tags: trees, bonsai

There's a folder in google drive where there are pictures attached.
Bought it in a local store but I do not know the species.
Could anyone help me?

[Link to Google Drive click here.](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1z3vqXDgbwKfhT2M6R0hguRmJb6PASUVz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear to be Chamaecyparis pisifera 'boulevard' - its an outdoor bonsai. I've never seen one of these as a bonsai, only as a small or dwarf  conifer in garden beds and borders, but there is some information here http://www.bonsai4me.co.uk/SpeciesGuide/Chamaecyparis.html on Chamaecyparis varieties grown as bonsai which might be helpful. There is no image of this particular variety in that link, but this link shows its foliage 
https://lebeaubamboo.com/Chamaecyparis-pisifera-Boulevard-Dwarf-Blue-Tipped-Cypress.php